# Approximate number of attempts given probability of specific combinations

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Suppose in a pool of infinite items in a box, there are 30 item types we care about. The chance of pulling each item type that we care about is 0.0333%.

So we have Y1 ... Y30, with each has the same probability (0.0333%).

Is our chance of getting (Y1, Y2, Y3) the same as getting (Y1, Y1, Y2)? The order doesn't matter, so for our purpose, (Y1, Y2, Y3) is the same as (Y2, Y1, Y3) or (Y3, Y2, Y1).

What would be the approximate number of items we have to try before we can get (Y1, Y2, Y3), is that number the same as if we try for (Y1, Y1, Y2) or any other combinations?

Thanks!

Comment: Try two equally likely outcomes sampled twice with replacement, say a fair coin.  Is $1$ heads and $1$ tails as likely as $2$ heads?

Comment: That's what I thought it would be, but not sure whether that's correct or not. Hence asking. Thanks!

Comment: Is multinomial distribution suitable for you to model the number of items for each type to be drawn?